# Unable to access preview site in cloud9 IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

Whenever I try to visit my preview site ("[application_name]-[my_username].c9users.io"), I get the timeout error as shown in picture below:

[Time Out Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PoOB.png)

I successfully used the preview site earlier, but suddenly it stopped working. This happens regardless of whether I run webrick server or not. I am trying to run tutorial site detailed in "https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up".

Comment: Did you try to curl your site internally to see if it was a Cloud9 issue or the rails code? `curl localhost:8080` and see if that times out too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to restart the server?  Just ctrl + C and then run bundle exec rail server -b $IP -p $PORT
And maybe restart the workspace

Comment: I restarted the workspace couple of times, but that didn't have any effect. I am not able to connect regardless of whether the brick server is running or not (although I did kill and run it many times). Previously if I tried to access the preview without the server running, it used to give me "could not find the page error".

Comment: Sounds strange!  Did you try to create a new workspace and see if that works?